# What is the proper method to add tests to modernizr?

Tags: javascript, modernizr, graceful-degradation

The test already exists in the github repo, but when I try to include it on my page I get an error, so I'm not sure how I need to include it in my document. In my html `<head>` tag I link the modernizr script and then link to the test I am adding:

```
<script src="js/modernizr-2.5.3-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/css-pointerevents.js"></script>
```

[css-pointerevents.js](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-pointerevents.js)

When I load the page now I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addTest'` which must be a reference to the first line of css-pointervents.js (`Modernizr.addTest('pointerevents', function(){`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because the addTest functionality is not included in the default base build of Modernizr . Need to add it specifically (under extensibility) http://modernizr.com/download/